# How to set default Google Sheets and Google Docs account?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-docs

I have two Google accounts that I always sign into, one of them is my personal account and the other belongs to the company I work for.

I created a desktop shortcut for both of these apps from chrome [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZh7B.png):

[image: like this]

I only use these apps with my work account.

When I click on these shortcuts, they take me to the accounts belonging to my personal Google account and then I would have to switch accounts. Is it possible to make them take me directly to my work account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such task, you are supposed to use **Manage People** where you will add your work account and then you can even create desktop shortcuts leading directly where you need.

[image: 0]

Comment: What is that? A chrome plugin? could you send a link?

Comment: that's actually chrome setting, not a plugin/extension. you just need to be logged in into chrome browser

Comment: My chrome looks like that https://www.bleepstatic.com/tutorials/web-browsers/chrome/reset-default-settings/open-settings.png I see  that no where and inside the settings, do you have the latest chrome?

Comment: I am signed into chrome on all my devices though and sync is turned on and chrome is my default browser

Comment: and what happens when you click here? -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpsjV.png (your chrome is kinda different from my latest version)

Comment: Yep I read that 5 min ago and was trying it, it works thank you https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en